# Generate x random numbers from specific range which doesn't duplicate and are not in a array

Tags: php

How I could generate a list of numbers (18 numbers), which are in a range which starts with 1 and ends with 36 (including 1 and 36), and the generated numbers must be different from numbers which exist in an array.

Example:
Array numbers: 27, 31, 18, 4, 15, 6

I need to output 18 random numbers which aren't in above array, and the numbers must not be duplicated.

Output I should get: 17, 21, 14, 28, 7, 8, 12, 20, 3, 5, 16, 2, 36, 11, 26, 13, 24, 35

```php
function randomGen($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $exluding_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    if(range($min, $max) === $exluding_array) {
        return "no";
    } else {
        return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
    }
}
```

With this code I get random numbers without duplicates, but the returned numbers can be numbers from `exluding_array`.

Comment: What does "but outputed numbers can be the numbers which are in string" mean?

Comment: I mean, the numbers which I get shouldn't the numbers which is in array , sorry for my bad english , I hope you will understand now . Thanks for your implication !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to remove all numbers of `excluding_array` from the generated `numbers` before slicing:

```php
function randomGen($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $excluding_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    // Remove unwanted numbers
    $numbers = array_diff($numbers, $excluding_array);
    shuffle($numbers);
    if (count($numbers) < $quantity) {
        return "no";
    } else {
        return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
    }
}
```

Note: I also improved your sanity check a bit, although returning "no" doesn't seem to be the best solution in that case. You might want to throw an exception as shown by vivek_23.

([Sample on PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d32c73b47f2b3d1fbaa3803ef0ca91d364d3f095))

Comment: if count($numbers) < $quantity  ?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is you can [array_flip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) the $excluding array and check for these numbers existence in $numbers. If we find them, we skip them, else we include it in our final array.

We could also throw an `Exception` if we can't produce as many numbers as `$quantity`.

```
<?php

function randomGen($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $exluding_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    $exluding_array = array_flip($exluding_array);
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    $filtered_numbers = [];
    foreach($numbers as $curr_number){
        if(isset($exluding_array[$curr_number])) continue;
        $filtered_numbers[] = $curr_number;
    }

    if(count($filtered_numbers) < $quantity) throw new Exception("Can't generate numbers with the given quantity and range.");

    return array_slice($filtered_numbers, 0, $quantity);
}


print_r(randomGen(1,36,10));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/mUi8A

You can also make the callee of this function implement a try-catch block to handle the exception gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter) to filter out the excluded numbers:

```
function randomGen(int $min, int $max, int $quantity, array $excluded = []): array
{
  $result = array_filter(range($min, $max), static function ($val) use ($excluded) {
    return !in_array($val, $excluded, true);
  });
  shuffle($result);
  return array_slice($result, 0, $quantity);
}

$result = randomGen(1, 36, 10, range(1, 10));
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/nkbTK**